# Looking for software crossover to output to multi-channel sound card

Tags: audio, sound-card, crossover

I want to send sound from any application running on Windows 7, separated by frequency range, to different audio-out ports of an onboard multichannel sound card (realtek HD audio).

For example, I want to put Mid to High (say 3KHz - 20KHz) frequencies through the front channel (configured at green port), and Low to Mid (say 150Hz - 3KHz) frequencies through the rear channel (configured at blue port). The audio as such is not multi-channel, it would be regular stereo audio, only want to divide the frequencies and play them through two different audio-out ports.

Is it possible with any software? and how?

Comment: Some terminology: you want to **filter** the signal by frequency content.  You are looking for a software **crossover**; the hardware equivalent is an **electronic crossover**.

Comment: professional software like Cubase would allow you to do this. But the answer to the 'how' question would be 'you have to figure that out yourself' as such software has quite a steep learning curve. Maybe simple solutions exist though.

Comment: Is a hardware (external) crossover out of the question?  Would probably be easier to run your computer's sound output to a physical crossover, and then run the output(s) of the crossover(s) to your individual speakers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the realtime crossover - xDSP (can be downloaded from http://dephonica.com).
Freeware version can record sound from a loopback sound input or 3-rd party virtual audio driver, process it and route to the analog or s/pdif soundcard output.

Comment: xDSP consumes too much CPU